# Flexbox - Vertically align both blocks and text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want `h2` with a `button` on the side like seen in the picture below:

[image]

I tried `flexbox`, but by centering the `button`, it doesn't fill full height anymore.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.header1 {
  align-items: center;
}
.button {
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header class="header1">
  <h2>Text centered but Button not full Height</h2>
  <a class="button" href="https://google.com">Read More</a>
</header>

<header class="header2">
  <h2>Button full height but Text not centered</h2>
  <a class="button" href="https://google.com">Read More</a>
</header>
```

Is there a way to achieve as pictured? I want to avoid adding Padding or fixed height to the button because then I need to adapt it for multiple media queries.

Answer (score 5):

Make your `button` a `flexbox` too and *vertically align* using `align-items: center` - see demo below:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.header1 {
  align-items: center;
}
.button {
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header2">
  <h2>Button full height but Text not centered</h2>
  <a class="button" href="https://google.com">Read More</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Great, never knew the solution would be this simple. I have lots to learn with flexbox.

Comment: I was just about to click **Post Your Answer** and I saw your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.header1 { align-items: center; }

.button {
  margin-left: auto;  
  background-color: yellow;
  display:block;
vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:30px;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 10px;
}
a span {
    display:block;
    height:50%;
  margin-top:-15px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header1">
  <h2>Text centered but Button not full Height</h2>
  <a class="button" href="https://google.com">Read More</a>
</header>

<header class="header2">
  <h2>Button full height but Text not centered</h2>
  <a class="button" href="https://google.com"><span></span>Read More</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this way is not clean because I need to change the sizing whenever the Title size changes